# Выборка из двух таблиц по FULL JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, mysql

Необходимо сделать выборку из двух таблиц

```
main
| id | total |
| 1  |    10 |
| 2  |    20 |
timed
| id | id_main | date_from  | date_to    | total |
| 1  |       2 | 2012-03-29 | 2012-04-29 |    50 |
```

Сджойнить таблицы так, чтобы результат был

```
| id | total |
| 1  |    10 |
| 2  |    50 |
```

Comment: Ну возможно не FULL JOIN, а LEFT JOIN и плюс ISNULL(timed.total, main.total).

Comment: или так

SELECT main.id AS id, COALESCE(timed.total, main.total) AS total
FROM main
LEFT JOIN timed
ON main.id = timed.id_main
AND SYSDATE() BETWEEN timed.date_from AND timed.date_to

Answer (score 3):

Так должно везде работать:

```
SELECT m.id AS [id],
   COALESCE(t.total, m.total) AS [total]
FROM main AS m
LEFT JOIN timed AS t
ON m.id = t.id_main;
```

[COALESCE](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_statement/page2.html)

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, так (MS SQL):

```
SELECT m.id AS [id],
   ISNULL(t.total, m.total) AS [total]
FROM main AS m
LEFT JOIN timed AS t
ON m.id = t.id_main;
```